# Call method Expression Tree in C#

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I want create expression with reflection in c#.

I am target script is:

```
using (var service = new MyProxy<IProductsService>())
{
    var response = service.DoAction<Response<List<Product>>>(srv => srv.GetProducts());
}
```

How to `(srv => srv.GetProducts()` script is generate with expression tree?

**Edit:**

I am sorry for the wrong expression.
wherein `IProductsService, Response<List<Product>>` and `GetProducts` are actually unknown types. I take generic on runtime.

I wrote the following methods(CreateExpression) to try. But `Expression property = Expression.Call(methodReturnType, methodName.Name, new Type[]{ } ,parameter);`  line gives the following error:

> No method 'GetProducts' exists on type
>   'ServiceFoundation.Response`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ServiceFoundation.Products.Product]]'.

Next in line for I have not tested it yet.

Method:

```
private void CreateExpression(Type interfaceType, Type methodReturnType, MethodInfo methodName)
    {
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(interfaceType, "srv");
    Expression property = Expression.Call(methodReturnType, methodName.Name, new Type[]{ } ,parameter);       
    Type expressionType = typeof(Expression<>);
    Type lambdaType = typeof(LambdaExpression);
    Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>);
    Type delegateType = funcType.MakeGenericType(interfaceType, methodReturnType);
    Type expression = expressionType.MakeGenericType(delegateType);

    MethodInfo mI = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Lambda");
    MethodInfo lambda = mI.MakeGenericMethod(delegateType);
    var ex = lambda.Invoke(this, new object[] { delegateType, property, parameter });
}
```

Hopefully I can express.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do…

Comment: Unfortunately, my english is not good :(  I'm trying to get this expression using Expression Trees: 'service.DoAction<Response<List<Product>>>(srv => srv.GetProducts());'

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create the expression `srv => srv.GetProducts()`? What does reflection have to do with this?

Comment: If you want to see how an expression is built, make the expression and see how it's built. You can see every single `Expression` the whole thing is made of, and then just recreate it as needed by your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded after a long struggle. I examined different questions here.
and in the end I solved this way:

```
 private Expression CreateExpression(Type interfaceType, Type methodReturnType, MethodInfo methodName)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(interfaceType, "srv");
            Expression callExpression = Expression.Call(parameter, methodName.Name,null, null);

            Type expressionType = typeof(Expression<>);
            Type lambdaType = typeof(LambdaExpression);
            Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType, methodReturnType);
            Type expressionGenericType = expressionType.MakeGenericType(funcType);

            string methodSignature = "System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression Lambda(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])";
            var lambdaMethod = typeof(Expression).GetMethods()
                .Single(mi => mi.ToString() == methodSignature);

            Expression lambdaExpression = (Expression)lambdaMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { callExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter } });
            return lambdaExpression;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an

```
Expression<Action<Response>>
```

you can call

```
.Compile()
```

on it and it returns an

```
Action<Response>
```

which you can then invoke normally.

eg

```
Expression<Action<Response>> exp = resp => Console.WriteLine(resp);
Action<Response> func = exp.Compile();
func(myResponse);
```

However, if that's all you need to do, you might find it simpler not to use expressions at all;

```
Action<Response> func = resp => Console.WriteLine(resp);
func(myResponse);
```